# How to shift an element in a sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

If the size of the shift is a parameter.

```
  def shiftN[A](s: Seq[A], nb: Int) : A => A =
    a => s((s.indexOf(a) + nb)%s.length)
```

But if the size of the shift is always the same (e.g. 1) and that the function will be called multiple times, we can do an optim. (So the overhead of building the map will be low regarding the gain of accessing directly the result).

```
  def shift1[A](s: Seq[A]) : A => A = {
    val shifted = s.tail :+ s.head
    val m = s.zip(shifted).toMap
    a => m(a)
  }
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I can avoid to construct the map every time by using an intermediate val : val shifter : A => A = shift1('a' to 'z'). The map will be built once and captured by the closure.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `s.toStream.tail ++ Stream(s.head)` is constant time ...